# WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading() documentation clarification

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient, webviewchromium

Referring to the API level **24+** only version of [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)), the documentation clearly states:

> **Note**: Do not call WebView#loadUrl(String) with the request's URL and
> then return true.  This unnecessarily cancels the current load and
> starts a new load with the same URL.   The correct way to continue
> loading a given URL is to simply return false, without calling
> WebView#loadUrl(String).

However, in my app I have to perform some extra activities before loading the URL that could only be done in MyWebView#loadUrl(String) and so I do call `MyWebView#loadUrl` from within `MyWebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading` then `return true;`.

This seems to work fine but I now have some doubts:

Does this warning about *"the correct way to continue loading a given URL"* mean that if I am **not** following it, this code could break

- in the future (as in "using undocumented internal API")
- or break now with some "unusual website"?

In what scenarios (e.g. frames, iframes, 301/302 redirects) this `return true;` scheme could break proper URL loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Handle Custom URLs portion of WebView docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#custom-urls)

It is unlikely that your method will directly break with normal URLs as long as they're valid URLs that conform to RFC 3986.

The primary concern with calling `loadURL` inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is it makes your app inefficient and leads to excessive web traffic (and in most cases is unnecessary if you're not actually modifying the URL or calling a different web page based on some kind of custom input format.

A way to rephrase would be to say, "If you're not changing the URL in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, then don't call `loadURL` again."

Basically, you're calling a web request twice when you don't need to.

In terms of returning true from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, the examples list a case where they return `true` because modification of the input URL was necessary, since they're using a custom format, that needs to be handled differently.

```
// The URL scheme should be non-hierarchical (no trailing slashes)
private static final String APP_SCHEME = "example-app:";

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME)) {
        urlData = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(APP_SCHEME.length()), "UTF-8");
        respondToData(urlData);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the above example, they're only overriding the behavior because they're using a custom format: `<a href="example-app:showProfile">`

So the app says "its this weird custom developer defined format, rather than a normal URL, so the app should instead use this custom `respondToData(urlData);`"

The issues you run into with WebView are like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911226/android-webview-4-4-converts-custom-url) where you make your own custom URL, except then the implementation of WebView expects something different (namely, a valid URL based on web standards)

This can be especially tricky if you are using a custom URL scheme or a base URL, that is not a valid URL that conforms to RFC 3986.  In those cases you may not properly trigger the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` callback.

You can also run into issues with [URI Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization) if you're not expecting that behavior.

As long as frames, iframes, and/or 301/302 redirects represent valid URL addresses and formats, then there should not be an issue.  However, in those cases, as long as you're not changing the URL within `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or using some type of custom response to the URL, then you don't need to call `WebView#loadURL` again.